# How difficult is it to source News Channel Logos?

Tags: film-techniques, film-industry

Nowadays, most movies and tv series tend to use actual brand logos (such as those of CNN, FOX etc eg. most recently in the movie *London Has Fallen*), I assume, to lend authenticity to their narrative.

My question  is how difficult is it to do the same and what procedure does the production crew need to go through to obtain the necessary rights to use a logo? Additionally, do the brands themselves make any money off of it?

Comment: This may be obvious, but it's worth noting that in some cases it likely wouldn't be very hard at all. Specifically when talking about Fox productions. For example in Prison Break everything news related appears on a Fox channel. The show was broadcast on Fox and created in association with 20th Century Fox Television. While I can't say this is also true for the X-Men franchise, it wouldn't be surprising if this was the case as Fox owns those rights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any other brand name used in film, Web, theatrical production etc. the answer is easy....and expensive....usually.

Many occasions we have needed specific brand police uniforms. Some forces we have a great relationship with, and authorization is simply sending them a script. Depending on the budget, some ask for a fee to use their intellectual properties, while others will allow smaller budget at little to no fee.

Every brand, name, police force, etc. owns the image to uniforms, logos, print material etc.

Even making a news cast using FOX. you would have to contact there intellectual properties division (and all big brand have an office that deals with movies and public events). They will most definitely want to see the script, the actors, and who the production team is. In all cases, this will take a few weeks.

Something as small as seeing a specific brand on a video without consent can cost a large legal bill, and a large law suite, and possibly have the project pulled. In many large feature films, when an actor is walking through a grocery store, either the product names are turned away, or the shelves are stocked with in heard of brands (these are movie look alike packages) because it would cost a fortune to get every single brand approved in a store.

If you can see the name, it has been paid for, or approved in writing.

We have our own 9 beer labels for bars, that we designed for film projects.